# Slider images don't work in internet explorer, but works in the other ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

http://teothemes.com/wp/

The slider is not showing up on internet explorer, but after I refresh it some times it starts working. Obviously that's not an acceptable behaviour, but I can't understand what the issue is.

It works fine on all the other browsers, firefox, safari, chrome...so it's just IE

It seems the JS scripts are not being loaded initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `console.log()` lines (or comment them out) in your js files, then it should work in IE.